# ctypes, python3.5, OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000000

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, python-3.5

Researching other similar errors, I think that I have an issue with a an illegal operation such as writing to an address that I shouldn't be. I'm not sure how to resolve this. Any help please?

Exact error I'm getting:

```
in GetSoftwareVersion()
result = f(LCP_Version, FCP_Version)
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000000
```

Functions I'm calling

```
x = GetSoftWareVersion()
print(x)
```

GetSoftwareVersion() contents

```
def GetSoftwareVersion():
    f = shim.GetSoftwareVersion

    LCP_Version = ct.c_char_p(0)
    FCP_Version = ct.c_char_p(0)

    result = f(LCP_Version, FCP_Version)

    if result:
        print(find_shim_error(result))

    return LCP_Version.contents.value, FCP_Version.contents.value
```

edit: adding the relevant C++ code

```
PCSHIMDLL_API  error_status_type GetSoftwareVersion(
        char* LCP_Version,
        char* FCP_Version
        )
{
    error_status_type return_status = SUCCESS;
    string LCP_V("");
    string FCP_V("");
    LaserIDType_var laserID;
    laserID = p_DiagIF->GetLaserID();
    LCP_V = laserID->m_LCPSoftwareVersion;
    FCP_V = laserID->m_FCPSoftwareVersion;
    strcpy(LCP_Version, LCP_V.c_str());
    strcpy(FCP_Version, FCP_V.c_str());

    return return_status;
}
```

Comment: What is `shim` (I assume it's a C dll), and how does `dpcGetSoftwareVersion` declaration (and description) look like? I see that you're passing 2 `NULL` `char` pointers, is that the intent? The function allocates memory for them and then stores some data in that memory (not a very usual practice). Or it expects 2 `char*`s pointing to an "allocated" area to store the data in (based on the error this seems to be the case)? Try initializing them using [ctypes.create_string_buffer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.create_string_buffer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting the error `OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000000` because of the statement `LCP_Version = ct.c_char_p(0)`.  As suggested by the [ctypes documentation for `c_char_p`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char_p) you're passing an integer address.

What you're telling `ctypes` to do is make a new `char *` pointing to `0`, then trying to `strcpy` to it via `strcpy(LCP_Version, LCP_V.c_str());`.  If you were to use `ct.c_char_p(1)`, you'd get `access violation writing 0x0000001`, if `c_char_p(2)`, then at `0x...2`, and so on.  It's very unlikely that your memory should or will want to allow you to write to that location, hence the error.

What you likely want to do is use [`create_string_buffer(N)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.create_string_buffer), where `N` is the size of the array needed to contain the output of `LCP_V = laserID->m_LCPSoftwareVersion;`.  `create_string_buffer`, as the name suggests, will give you a mutable char buffer that's initialized to null bytes (e.g. `p = create_string_buffer(3)` means `p` is size 3, with contents `b'\x00\x00\x00`).  You could guess and check or look at the source of `p_DiagIF->GetLaserID();` to hunt down the safe value of `N`, or just give yourself something huge (for a version number) like `LCP_Version = ct.c_char_p(50)` and pick something sane from there.