# Ctypes Extending Python and returning Arrays (2D)

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, ctypes

I am currently trying to write a C++ method that can be called by a python file that I have. I am using python's `ctypes` library and have come across countless errors in the process. So far all I want my method to do is take in an array as its arguments and return an array as a result. I've read countless threads on StackOverflow and can't find a solution that runs without errors. Here's what I've been trying.

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np

c_lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r"C:\Users\~user~\Desktop\~folder~\file.dll")

c_lib.method.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64) # result should be integer array (in this case it should be a 2D array with an unknown shape)
c_lib.method.argtypes = [np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=ctypes.c_int64), ctypes.c_int64] # the arguments should be an array (also with an unknown shape)

x = [[0,1], [2,3], [1,1], [86,100], [87,99], [100,100]] 
array = np.array(x, dtype = ctypes.c_int64) # make python list a numpy array

y = c_lib.method(array, 5)
```

Currently I am getting this error:

`OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000000`

Here is my C++ code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C"{

vector<tuple<int, int>> group_coordinates(int** array, int number);

vector<tuple<int, int>> group_coordinates(int** coordinates, int max_deviation){
    vector<tuple<int, int>> group_coordinates(int** coordinates, float max_deviation){
    vector<vector<int>> mean_x_groups = {{coordinates[0][0]}};
    vector<vector<int>> mean_y_groups = {{coordinates[0][0]}};
    vector<tuple<int, int>> grouped_coordinates;
    
    int mean_x, mean_y;
    // this goes through the points, finds the if a point is within the max deviation of the mean coordinate (this mean updates as coordinates are added)
    // if a point doesn't fit the deviation than it will be added to a new group of its own
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(coordinates); i++)
    {
        int* point = coordinates[i];
        int len_mxg = mean_x_groups.size();
        int len_myg = mean_y_groups.size();
        tie(mean_x, mean_y) = mean_xy(mean_x_groups[len_mxg-1], mean_y_groups[len_myg-1]);
        if ((point[0] <= mean_x + max_deviation && point[0] >= mean_x - max_deviation) && (point[1] <= mean_y + max_deviation && point[1] >= mean_y - max_deviation)){
            // before a new group is added, the point will be checked to see if it can within any of the old groups
                    // if it is it will be added, if it isn't, a new group of its own ill be made
            for(int index = 0; index < len_mxg; index++){
                int mean_x, mean_y;
                tie(mean_x, mean_y) = mean_xy(mean_x_groups[index], mean_y_groups[index]);
                if ((point[0] <= mean_x + max_deviation && point[0] >= mean_x - max_deviation) && (point[1] <= mean_y + max_deviation && point[1] >= mean_y - max_deviation)){
                                mean_x_groups[index].push_back(point[0]);
                                mean_y_groups[index].push_back(point[1]);
                }
                else{
                    mean_x_groups.push_back({point[0]});
                    mean_y_groups.push_back({point[1]});
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            mean_x_groups[len_mxg-1].push_back(point[0]);
            mean_y_groups[len_myg-1].push_back(point[1]);   
        }
    }
    // this uses the sorting above an retruns the mean (x, y) pair of each group
    // the enumerate here was me playing with the fuction, seemed to orgainze the sorting cleaner looking
    int len_mxg = mean_x_groups.size();
    int len_myg = mean_y_groups.size();
    for (int index = 0; index < len_mxg; index++){
            tie(mean_x, mean_y) = mean_xy(mean_x_groups[index], mean_y_groups[index]);
            grouped_coordinates.push_back(make_tuple(mean_x, mean_y));
    }
    return grouped_coordinates; 
}
}
```

I found this thread [ctypes, python3.5, OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37973033/ctypes-python3-5-oserror-exception-access-violation-writing-0x00000000#comment63394192_37973033) but couldn't make an applicable solution using the answer.

At this point I'm not sure if I should continue perusing `ctypes` (I don't want to give up though... but I have tried a countless number of unsuccessful solutions) or if I should try a different C++ Python linker.

If anyone knows how I could fix the access violation Error, can help me with fixing my code, or can provide me with more resources to look into, that would be greatly appreciated!

Here are other threads/resources I've looked into:

[How to return array from C++ function to Python using ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887378/how-to-return-array-from-c-function-to-python-using-ctypes)

https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/59536/how-to-return-array-from-c-function-to-python-using-ctypes

https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/numerical_sage/ctypes.html

https://nesi.github.io/perf-training/python-scatter/ctypes

[Python 2D array i C using ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148188/python-2d-array-i-c-using-ctypes)

Comment: Why did you bother pasting all those irrelevant methods, while the relevant one isn't? What;s with the *C++* code? There are a bunch of errors in your code (*int* != *int64*, ...). Please comply with [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58727931/how-to-pass-a-2d-array-from-python-to-c, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58226790/c-python-pass-and-return-a-2d-double-pointer-array-from-python-to-c/58262388#58262388 (it surely is one of them).

Comment: Ill check this out and get back to you. Thank you for the help. Not really sure why I put that C++ code in there (sorry, new to asking questions on here).

Comment: No worries. I'd be also curious to see how *new\_2D\_array* is created / manipulated inside the function.

Comment: Ill put the code in. This method should return a vector of tuples but I would turn this into an array when I make the final method (don't know how to return vectors or tuples in python).

Comment: You can't (or shouldn't). Those are ***C++***, while you use ***C**Types*. You could also check *PyBind11*.

Comment: Should I just write my project in C++ entirely? I am trying to make an OpenCV program. Would it be worth my time to peruse the Python and C++ route or just C++ (I am much more experienced in Python but am using C++ because I need the speed, I have experience in Java and could make the transition to C++ with some practice).